# No database entries when iterate array from database Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

```
protected function show()
{
    $users = User::all();
    $letters = Letter::with('user');
     $userLetter = $letters->where(['user_id' => 2])->count();
     //Here function work right. Shows that we have 10 users
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $userLetter = $letters->where(['user_id' => $user->id])->first();
        if($userLetter){
            //Here it shows that only the first user exists, returns null for the rest users.
        }
    }
}
```

We get an error when we sort the array with foreach. 
No record is found in the database except the first.
For other entries, return null.
outside foreach no errors.

Comment: it shows first because you query asks for first. Please just put `get();` instead of `first();`.

Comment: `if($userLetter !== null)`

Comment: These methods do not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move your object inside the loop like below.

```
    protected function show()
    {
        $users = User::all();
         $userLetter = $letters->where(['user_id' => 2])->count();
         //Here function work right. Shows that we have 10 users
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $userLetter = Letter::with('user')->where(['user_id' => $user->id])->first();
            if($userLetter){

            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Because you are not clear (reset) your object after iteration complete. `$letters` object adding multiple conditions every time until loop doesn't complete.
Its become like this `Letter::with('user')->where('user_id' => 1)->where('user_id' => 2)->where('user_id' => n)`

Comment: Understood @Dmitry?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably be better off using a letter relationship on the `User`.

On the `User` model you could do something like :

```
public function letter()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Letter::class, 'user_id');
}
```

Then you could in the controller:

```
protected function show()
{
    $users = User::with('letter')->get();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        if ($user->letter) {
            // do things
        }
    }
}
```